# trying to convert time stamp but getting pattern datetimeformatter error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a created column as type `string` that I'm trying to convert to `Datetime`

Format looks like this: 7/26/2021 10:12:48 PM

I tried the following but getting error message:

```py
display(
    sdf.select(
        "*", F.to_timestamp(F.col("created"), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").alias("dt")
    )
)
```

When I remove one 'a' I get only `NULLs`

Comment: What is the "error message" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a date with `/` and you try to parse it with `-`.

try this : `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([["7/26/2021 10:12:48 PM"]], ["created"]).select(
    "*", F.to_timestamp(F.col("created"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").alias("dt")
)

df.show()
+--------------------+-------------------+
|             created|                 dt|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|7/26/2021 10:12:4...|2021-07-26 22:12:48|
+--------------------+-------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I got the following error messages . Text '7/26/2021 10:12:48 PM' could not be parsed at index 0.
You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string

Comment: Have you tried to "set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY" ?